# Tridion 2011 with DD4T - UI 2012 settings does not seem to use BluePrint Context

Tags: tridion, dd4t

I am trying to iron out a couple of issues with UI2012 in my app and cannot seem to get my Components to be editable in the right context. I always have to click "Edit this component everywhere" or "Localize this component" in order to edit something.

My Blueprint is pretty simple at the moment:

- 00 - Empty Present
- 01 - Schemas
- 02 - Common Functionality
- 03c - Content (id = 5)
- 03d - Design
- 06 - Website (id = 9)

Here is my siteedit_config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<siteEdit enabled="true" style="SiteEdit2012" tridionHostUrl="http://mycmsurl">
  <contextPublications>
    <contextPublication id="9" componentPublication="5" pagePublication="9" publishPublication="9" />
  </contextPublications>
</siteEdit>
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Did you configure the Blueprint options in the UI Dashboard?

Comment: Facepalm! Thanks Nuno. Answer for free rep :)

Comment: Btw, UI2012 doesn't use siteedit_conf.xml! All the settings are stored in the CM Application Data or Tridion/web/WebUI/Editors/SiteEdit/Configuration/SiteEditEditor.conf

Comment: @BorisPonomarenko I still need siteedit_config.xml to enable/disable and to tell DD4T to output the JSON in the right format.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The **Blueprint Context Settings** are defined in the Experience Manager dashboard. Open any page that is XPM-Enabled and then:

- Click on the Dashboard Tab
- Click on Settings
- Click on Blueprint Context Settings
- Select the Publication for which you want to change the default settings (the "Published" publication)
- Select where to create new components and pages for this publication
- Apply Changes

This should do it.